# Inserting into a Tree

Tags: java, tree

**EDIT**: proper solution:

```
void add(Student s)
{
    if(root == null)
        root = new TreeNode(s);
    else
        insert(root,s);        
}

void insert(TreeNode tn, Student s)
{
    if(tn.sVal.compareTo(s) > 0)
    {
        if(tn.left != null)
            insert(tn.left, s);            
        else
        {
            tn.left = new TreeNode(s);
            tn.left.parent = tn;
        }
    }
    else if(tn.sVal.compareTo(s) < 0)
    {
        if(tn.right != null)
            insert(tn.right, s);
        else
        {
            tn.right = new TreeNode(s);
            tn.right.parent = tn;
        }
    }
    balance(tn);
}
```

---

I'm trying to inserting to a binary tree using the following:

```
void add(Student s)
    {
        insert(root,s);
    }

private void insert(TreeNode t, Student s)
{        
    if(t == null)
        t = new TreeNode(s);        
    else if(t.sVal.compareTo(s) > 0)
        insert(t.right, s);
    else if(t.sVal.compareTo(s) < 0)
        insert(t.left,s);                
}
```

However, the tree remains empty, and I can't figure out why. I hate to be so vague, but I can't find an error in the logic. What am I missing?

Comment: What is `root` here in the method call `insert(root,s);`?

Comment: All you do is create a new tree node--you never actually insert it into the tree.

Comment: @DaveNewton - the new node assigned to t, which should be reference to a node in the tree. For example, if the tree is empty, the root is null, and root = t = new node. At least, that the logic that I'm following.

Comment: @Mong134 And that is why what you're doing is failing, because an assumption you're making is incorrect.

Comment: @Lion - root is the root node of the tree

Comment: Also, this smells of homework, and should be tagged as such if it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a big hint: Make this change first, then debug from there:

```
if (t == null)
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
```

And a still bigger hint: When you create the new node, you must also have a reference to its parent so you can add it to the parent.

Comment: I think I might be getting more confused. If t = null, aren't I at a leaf, where the new node should be inserted, or possibly dealing with an empty tree?

Comment: I get it now. That's all I needed.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is showing a basic misunderstanding of Java, and I'll try to help you understand where you're going wrong.

When you call `insert(root,s)`, you're passing a **reference** to the same TreeNode **object** pointed to by `root`. When you then assign `t = new TreeNode(s)` inside the `insert` function, you are assigning a **new reference** to `t`, **NOT** to `root`.

Java is pass-by-value, and in the case of objects, that means it is passing the *value of the reference*. If you know C, you can think of it as a pointer. It is passing the memory address, not passing the pointer that points to the memory address.

Answer (score 0):

It's a pointer issue. When you redefine pointer `a` using the `=` operator, all previous references to `a` are lost. In order to keep these references, you either have to change the object using member functions (class methods in Java) or write code to **directly** fix the references.

Put simply, redefining a pointer affects only that pointer. Anything which already references the pointer will **not** be updated.

Pseudocode Example:

```
Node a = new Node("hello")
Node b = a
a = new Node("goodbye")

print(a) // this prints "goodbye"
print(b) // this prints "hello"
```

In order for `b` to point to the new `a`, you must write `b = a`.

Having sorted that out, you will need to rewrite your `insert()` method. Because a tree is recursive, a recursive `insert()` method should do the trick. There are a variety of resources online for recursive tree implementations if you need them: [Recursive Tree Java](http://www.java-forums.org/java-lang/7614-binary-tree-implementation-java.html)